# Trying to write a jQuery plugin called $.myAjax

Tags: jquery

I'm starting to see a pattern that I'm using for all my $.ajax calls, so I'd like to write a jQuery plugin called myAjax:

```
var myXHR = $.myAjax(myURL, mySettings)
```

and it will will always include the following:

```
myXHR.done(function(result) {
    if (result.MSG) {
        $('#msg').html(result.MSG).addClass('alert alert-info');
    }
})
.fail(function(A,B,C) {
    $('#msg').html(C).addClass('alert alert-info');
});
```

I also want to include the defaults that I use regularly:

```
var ajaxDefaults = {};
ajaxDefaults.type= 'POST'
ajaxDefaults.dataType='json';
$.ajaxSetup(ajaxDefaults);
```

Q: How do I write a plugin to do those two things:

1. Include the defaults for type and dataType
2. Include a default .done and .fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a plugin in jQuery is quite simple as you follow your own documentation.

[JQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

So for your case it will:

```
(function($) {
      $.extend($.fn, {
    myAjax: function(url, options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajaxDefaults, options);
        //your code....
            }
    /*
    * plugn defaults
    */
    ajaxDefaults : {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    }
    }); 
}(jQuery));
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I think you have to end your self-invoking function with: )()

Comment: 'options' is colored differently using Dreamweaver.  That's why I use naming like 'myOptions'

Comment: Should your second $.extend be $.ajax maybe?

Comment: To call the function of this plugin simply: var options = {//your options} and $.myAjax(url, options); ... and another functions will be equals.

Comment: To call default options call: $.ajaxDefaults.type = "GET" or $.ajaxDefaults = options.... please read jquery documentation =]

Comment: Anderson, your solution puts ajaxDefaults into the $.fn namespace.  Is there a better way to do this so that my plugin doesn't use 2 names?

Comment: read this... http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/